Need to convert string to Array of objects in single jolt
INPUT JSON
{
  "systemName": "[\"R342\",\"EEFCP\",\"SBLLL\",\"NOW\",\"SLLV\",\"CXLX\",\"ES\",\"SC\"]",
  "externalId": "[\"121461\",\"135630\",\"1-23L-270\",\"faa0dd954f452f0087418d9f9310c775\",\"1046\",\"9357\",\"1863899966\",\"00180067670000k7F1FAAU\"]"
}

Expected Output
{
  "externalSystemIds": [
    {
      "systemName": "R342",
      "systemId": "121461"
    },
    {
      "systemName": "EEFCP",
      "systemId": "135630"
    },
    {
      "systemName": "SBLLL",
      "systemId": "1-23L-270"
    },
    {
      "systemName": "NOW",
      "systemId": "faa0dd954f452f0087418d9f9310c775"
    },
    {
      "systemName": "SLLV",
      "systemId": "1046"
    },
    {
      "systemName": "CXLX",
      "systemId": "9357"
    },
    {
      "systemName": "ES",
      "systemId": "1863899966"
    },
    {
      "systemName": "SC",
      "systemId": "00180067670000k7F1FAAU"
    }
  ]
}

STEP 1 JOLT
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "externalId": "externalSystemIds.externalId",
      "sysName": "externalSystemIds.sysName"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "externalSystemIds": {
        "tempId1": "=split('\"',@(1,externalId))",
        "tempId2": "=join('',@(1,tempId1))",
        "tempId3": "=split(']',@(1,tempId2))",
        "tempId4": "=join('',@(1,tempId3))",
        "tempIdlen": "=size(@(1,tempId4))",
        "tempId5": "=substring(@(1,tempId4),1,@(1,tempIdlen))",
        "externalIds": "=split(',',@(1,tempId5))",
        "tempName1": "=split('\"',@(1,sysName))",
        "tempName2": "=join('',@(1,tempName1))",
        "tempName3": "=split(']',@(1,tempName2))",
        "tempName4": "=join('',@(1,tempName3))",
        "tempNamelen": "=size(@(1,tempName4))",
        "tempName5": "=substring(@(1,tempName4),1,@(1,tempNamelen))",
        "systemNames": "=split(',',@(1,tempName5))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "externalSystemIds": {
        "temp*": "",
        "sysName": "",
        "externalId": ""
      }
    }
  }
]

STEP 2 JOLT
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "externalSystemIds": {
        "systemNames": {
          "*": {
            "@": "externalSystemIds[&1].systemName"
          }
        },
        "externalIds": {
          "*": {
            "@": "externalSystemIds[&1].systemId"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]


Hi Karthik. Are you using Jolt on NiFi ?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@Community no worries about code but about platform and/or tag

Yes was using Nifi but  now expecting in microservices, so improve the efficiency looking for single jolt

Nifi has better tecniques to solve your issue(provided you're currently using)

The best way is to do this dynamically with the following spec:
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "sysNSize": "=size(@(1,systemName))",
      "sysNLengthNoEndBracket": "=intSubtract(@(1,sysNSize),2)",
      "sysNNoSquareBrackets": "=substring(@(1,systemName),1,@(1,sysNLengthNoEndBracket))",
      "systemNameArray": "=split('[\",]',@(1,sysNNoSquareBrackets))",
      "externalIdsize": "=size(@(1,externalId))",
      "extIdLengthNoEndBracket": "=intSubtract(@(1,externalIdsize),2)",
      "extIdNoSquareBrackets": "=substring(@(1,externalId),1,@(1,extIdLengthNoEndBracket))",
      "externalIdArray": "=split('[\",]',@(1,extIdNoSquareBrackets))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": { // the level of the array "key"
        "*": { // the level of the indexes of the array 
          "": null,
          "*": { // the values other than ""s
            "@1": "&3" // @1 replicates the innermost values as a whole
              // while matches &3 which copies the literal "key"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "systemNameArray": {
        "*": {
          "@": "externalSystemIds.[&1].systemName",
          "@(2,externalIdArray[&])": "externalSystemIds.[&1].systemId"
        }
      }
    }
   }
]

I borrowed the second shift from @Barbaros Özhan: Remove empty string from array using JOLT Transform. For some reason this kinda of cleanup always give me hard time :) despite it looks simple.
If anyone think there is better way with less # of spec please provide your feedback.
Thanks
